The laptop turns off for no apparent reason
The Dell latitude 5430 model
Ubuntu 24.04
The battery is 100% and the power is connected.
There is no overheating.
For no apparent reason, the effect of the keys sticking (different) occurs and after a few seconds the computer turns off. I tried to review the logs but couldn't figure out the reason. I'm not a strong user, so I'm asking for help.
last rows from journal
Dec 12 16:12:25 ff7flaptop dbus-daemon[15641]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.>
Dec 12 16:12:47 ff7flaptop dbus-daemon[15641]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.>
Dec 12 16:13:32 ff7flaptop dbus-daemon[15641]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.>
Dec 12 16:15:02 ff7flaptop CRON[43131]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Dec 12 16:15:02 ff7flaptop CRON[43132]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 16:15:02 ff7flaptop CRON[43131]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-300)
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-310)
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: 
                                   Initialized Local Variables for Method [ECR1]:
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel:   Local0: 00000000153c1d37 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECR1]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg0:   00000000ebdccf91 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000090
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.ECR1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \ECRB due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:39 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV._Q79 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-300)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-310)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: 
                                   Initialized Local Variables for Method [ECR1]:
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel:   Local0: 0000000083de365a <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECR1]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg0:   0000000031c83acb <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000090
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.ECR1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \ECRB due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.UBTC: failed to evaluate _DSM c298836f-a47c-e411-ad36-631042b5008f (0x11)
Dec 12 16:15:41 ff7flaptop kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 2
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-300)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-310)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg0:   00000000a2b648ec <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000033
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg1:   000000004cc6703b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.EXRW due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:44 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.TMEM._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-300)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-310)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg0:   00000000c8e49891 <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000A0
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg1:   0000000079f0e27c <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \ECWB due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.UBTC: failed to evaluate _DSM c298836f-a47c-e411-ad36-631042b5008f (0x11)
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 1
Dec 12 16:15:46 ff7flaptop kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: con2: failed to register partner alt modes (-5)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230628/evregion-300)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20230628/evregion-310)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [ECW1]
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [ECW1]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg0:   000000005b277d88 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000033
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel:   Arg1:   00000000ab2dcdb2 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000005
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: 
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.ECW1 due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.EXRW due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.KDRT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)
Dec 12 16:15:49 ff7flaptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV.HTTP._TMP due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20230628/psparse-529)


Could you paste the output of journalctl -b -1

The embeddedcontrol ae_timeout sometimes pops up for various laptops, it's a hardware fault or hw related firmware. Check if there is a new bios firmware available for your laptop, maybe this is a bug that was already fixed? It apparently can also be caused by a failing hard disk. I don't think it's Ubuntu specific, does the laptop still have warranty? The vendor should have the knowledge to troubleshoot failing hardware

Well, I updated the BIOS, updated the system firmware from 1.24.0 to 1.25.0. (via Windows, Linux gave an error when updating).
It didn't affect anything, the reboot is still with me.
